# Does $x$ include $1$ and $y$ when we say $x\mid y$?

Tags: divisibility

I'm new to number theory. If we have a statement saying $n\mid91$, does it mean that $n$ can be $1, 7, 13, 91$, or n can be $7, 13$. Is $1$ and $91$ excluded?

Comment: It includes 1 and 91

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @MatthewDaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bare statement $n\mid91$ *does include* the possibility that $n=1$ or $n=91$, since it is true that $1\mid91$ and $91\mid91$. Only if we said "$n$ is a *non-trivial divisor* of $91$" would $n=1,91$ be excluded from consideration.

Answer (score 0):

"$x\mid y$" is shorthand for (or as we mathematicians say it, *is defined as*) "There is an integer $n$ such that $nx = y$". Nothing about $x\neq 1$ or $x\neq y$ in there. In fact, $1\mid y$ is *always* true, for any integer $y$, and I can imagine there are contest problems where this is used to show that some unknown number is indeed $1$.

This also means that we get $0\mid 0$, which isn't encountered often, but it's a fun little consequence that one might not consider.